# Vertically align a img inside a div?

Tags: css, sass

Does anyone know what I am missing to vertically align a img inside a div?

I have some sass, though I can work with plain CSS too.

I thought `text-align` was sufficient ? But it isn't working. The margin and height are automatically set on the `<img>` so G know that is working.

```
.testdiv {
  font-size: rem(12);
  height: 80px;
  img {
    margin-left: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

and some html

```
<div class="testdiv">
    <img src="./test.png">
</div>
```

Comment: text-align is HORIZONTAL alignment. it has nothing to do with vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y0bcdd3/)**

`text-align` has nothing to do with `vertical-align`

there are a number of ways to `vertical-align` items, one of them is `display:flex`

code :

```
.testdiv {
  font-size: rem(12);
  height: 80px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid red;
      img {
        margin-left: 0px;
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
        text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yep, got this working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table-cell` css property to vertically align an element inside a parent.

```css
.testdiv {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: rem(12);
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="testdiv">
  <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Image Description">
</div>
```